# Registering a user control always postback hen the form loaded

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, postback

Hi all I have created a user control and registered it in `web.config` with some extension and calling it on the page where ever required. When I use that when ever the page get loaded the user control also getting loaded, i mean the post back event of the user control or the page load event occurs as per the operations made in web page.

Is there any way to avoid this in such a way that only the user control page load should enable or load when ever some operations performed on that control when loaded.

For example I have created a user control and registered on my form, this will get loaded on button click of the form, I would like to make the post back of user control only when user click on the button of the web form but not on every operations performed

`Edit as per jadarnel27 answer`

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl1.ascx" TagName="TimeoutControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Panel ID="yourPanelControl" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px">
        </asp:Panel>
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn" Text="user" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server">
        </dx:ASPxButton>

 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeoutControl tc = new TimeoutControl();
            yourPanelControl.Controls.Add(tc);
        }
```

But I am unable to see the postback event fires on page load of user control as per ur code

Answer (score 1):

When the ASP.NET Page loads, it recursively calls the `Load` function of all the controls in the `Page.Controls` collection (see the "Life Cycle events" section of [this MSDN article on The ASP.NET Page Life Cylce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#lifecycle_events), specifically the "Load" event).  Including the UserControl in the markup of your page will cause it to be part of this collection, so the load event will fire whenever the Page loads.

If you want to avoid this, you need to add the UserControl to the Page dynamically in response to the Button's click event.  You could, for instance, include some kind of Panel in your Page, then add the UserControl to that Panel when you click the Button.

Something like this:

```
protected void yourButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create your UserControl
    yourUserControl uc = new yourUserControl();
    // Add it to the Panel you included in your markup
    yourPanelControl.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

The markup for a Panel would be something like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="yourPanelControl" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px">
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Check my edits and let me know where I went wrong and also when we register a user control in web.config how can we get the name

Comment: @Dotnet So what is wrong after you added that code?  I don't understand.

Comment: Unable to load the user control on button click